# Why does not Flink retry operator failures?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am planning to migrate one of our Spark application to Apache Flink. I am trying to understand its fault tolerance feature.

I executed following code, I do not see that Flink actually tries to retry any task(or subtask). This can cause a data loss for me. What should I do to make sure that every failures covered by Flink?

```
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    env.setStateBackend(new FsStateBackend("file:///my-path", false))
    env.setRestartStrategy(RestartStrategies.fixedDelayRestart(
      3, // number of restart attempts
      Time.of(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // delay
    ))
    env.enableCheckpointing(10L)
    val text = env.socketTextStream(hostName, port)
    text
      .map { input =>
        List(input)
      }.setParallelism(1)
      .flatMap { input =>
        println(s"running for $input")
        List.fill(5)(input.head) ::: {
          println("throw exception here")
          throw new RuntimeException("some exception")
          List("c")
        }
      }
```

I expect to see `throw exception here` message couple of times on the screen. However, when I use `fixedDelayRestart`, it looks like it just ignores this message and continue for others.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you start the application.

I assume that you are running this out of your IDE. In that case `StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment` returns a `LocalStreamExecutionEnvironment` which runs the program and all of Flink in a single process, i.e., master (in Flink JobManager) and worker (TaskManager) are started as threads in the same JVM process. The exception terminates this single process. Hence, there is no Flink process left that could restart the program.

If you want to run the program with fault tolerance, you need to submit it to a Flink environment, for example one that runs on your local machine. Download the Flink distribution, extract the archive file, and run `./bin/start-cluster.sh`. This will start two processes, a master and a worker process. You can then submit the program to the cluster by creating a remote execution environment with `StreamExecutionEnvironment.createRemoteEnvironment` and passing hostname and port as parameters (please check the documentation for details).

Note that the exception will still kill the worker process. So in order to be able to restart the program, you'll need to manually start a worker process. In a production environment, this is typically taken care of by Kubernetes, Yarn, or Mesos.

By the way, we recently added an operations playground to the Flink documentation. It's a Docker-based sandbox environment to play around with Flink's fault-tolerance features. I recommend to check it out: [Flink Operations Playground](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/getting-started/docker-playgrounds/flink-operations-playground.html).

Some more hints:

- A checkpointing interval of 10ms is *very* short.
- A text socket source does not provide at-least-once (or exactly-once) guarantees. Records are processed at-most-once.

Comment: Thanks Fabian for the answer that helps a lot. Could you please explain more your hints? Does the source is at-most-once mean data loss in any way? Does not checkpoint keeps the record?

Comment: Yes, a text socket source will most likely lose records in case of a failure. The text socket source is not meant for production, just for simple demonstrations. It does not include records in checkpoints, hence all records that were read after the last successful checkpoint cannot be reprocessed. I'd recommend to ingest streams via a persisting message queue like Kafka or Pulsar.

Comment: Thank you that clears a lot of stuff. I do not want to get out of the question context, but checkpoints are not very clear to me. I have a production service that process PB scale data daily with Spark. We want to move this to Flink, but fault tolerance mechanics are not very clear. Our flow is;
Kinesis(contains s3 object path) -> Download and process content -> buffer for X minutes -> Write S3. It must be transactional, does checkpoints keep data(for us it is very big), or just metadata such as offset coming from Kinesis? Any failure in any operation, we do want to reprocess the file again.

Comment: A checkpoint contains both: 1) position information of sources (offsets of Kinesis), and 2) the intermediate state of operators (the data that is buffered). Flink's checkpointing algorithm guarantees that a checkpoint is consistent, i.e., all data was copied at "conceptually" the same point of time. In case of a failure, everything (reading positions & buffered data) are reset to the last completed checkpoint and the application continues from that consistent point. In your use case, the recovered Flink program would read all files again that were processed after the last checkpoint.

Comment: This is great, but if we window data for couple of minutes, this is already a lot of data(TB) in memory, how efficient to keep these in checkpoints?

Comment: In general, more data means more checkpointing overhead. However, Flink can store state on disk (via RocksDB) and supports asynchronous and incremental checkpoints. There are Flink applications with 10+TB state.